# What is a adjective to describe a champion who eventually wins after many setbacks?

Tags: idioms, adjectives

friends, I am very glad to be on this forum! Here I am sending you greetings! :)

Would you please share with me what adjective would you suggest describing a winner, a champion, who will win the final battle but will encounter many obstacles, hardships, oppositions, and mockeries?

I was thinking like "battled Champion"? "Scarred Champion"? Something along the lines.

Comment: It's old-fashioned, but "doughty" means someone who is brave and perseveres through adversity.

Comment: Consider heroic champion.

Comment: Consider *cliché*. Practically every "champion" movie you ever see has that exact storyline.

Comment: Surely this is answered somewhere on TVTropes.com, with a name for every possible slight plot difference. Also, didn't Kurt Vonnegut identify the 6 plot arcs that almost all plots follow?

Comment: ["Man in a Hole"](https://www.theatlantic.com/technology/archive/2016/07/the-six-main-arcs-in-storytelling-identified-by-a-computer/490733/) is a label Vonnegut gives to the 'redemption' plot, but it is not a term I've heard before (and so don't expect to have much currency).

Comment: I would not call it "cliche" because "cliche" has a negative undertone that means something unattractive. I would call this common storyline "perennial". Would love to hear what adjectives you may suggest? Thank you!

Comment: Dan Jansen.  ...

Comment: Sounds like a **survivor**?  A person who copes well with difficulties in their life and finally come out as survivor.

Answer (score 1):

He has finally realized his **long-sought** dream of becoming champion.

She has finally captured her **[sought-after](https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/sought-after)** championship.

Comment: I’d argue this better describes the goal than the person achieving it.

Answer (score 0):

He is a " go getting champion" or " an assiduous/ardent achiever"  you should better go for the world " achiever " because for such a person success is hard to come by but he's importunate come what may.

Answer (score 0):

I would define them as a **Fighter** as defined by [dictionary.com](https://www.dictionary.com/browse/fighter)

> a person who fights, struggles, resists, etc.